# How to boost results from suggester, but not filter with elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elastic Search 5.6.

I am using the completion suggester to return results in a search field. I have mapped and index my documents successfully. I also am getting results that are close to the desired result.

In the docs, it's mentioned that a context could be implemented to boost and/or filter results seen here:

> the completion suggester considers all documents in the index, but it
>   is often desirable to serve suggestions filtered and/or boosted by
>   some criteria.

**My problem is,** however, I'm receiving filtered results only....not simply boosted results. If I'm reading the docs right, I should be able to boost without filtering. [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/suggester-context.html)

This problem is evident in a simple example. Let's say the search query is "Portland". The user is Portland, ME so I would like to boost that result higher than Portland, OR. However, currently my context is filtering the results, so instead of Portland, ME *and* Portland, OR being returned, just Portland, ME is being returned because it's within the context zone.

Mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "destination" : {
            "_all": {"enabled": false},
            "properties" :  {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "suggest": {
                    "type": "completion",
                    "analyzer": "simple",
                    "contexts": {
                        "name": "location",
                        "type": "geo",
                        "path": "location"
                    }
                },
                "type": {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "state": {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point",
                    "index": true
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example Indexed Document:

```
{
  "name": "Portland",
  "location": [
    -70.25533,
    43.66147
  ],
  "suggest": {
    "input": "Portland"
  },
  "state": "ME",
  "type": "city"
}
```

Finally, my query:

```
{
        "suggest": {
            "query-suggest" : {
                "prefix" : search_query,
                "completion": {
                    "field" : "suggest",
                    "size": 10,
                    "contexts": {
                        "location": [ 
                            {
                                "lat": loc.latitude,
                                "lon": loc.longitude,
                                "precision": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "context": {
                                    "lat": loc.latitude,
                                    "lon": loc.longitude
                                },
                                "boost": 2
                            }
                         ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }  
    };
```

Depending on where the location is set, ES is only returning results within that's geo context. I want boosted values in that geo context, not filter. How can I get boosted values based on my geo context without filtering them thus returning the boosted values first, then the next highest scored documents which could possibly be outside the geo context.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742159/boost-results-matching-terms-query-without-filtering-in-elasticsearch has a hacky workaround but no nice answer.

Comment: Not quite the same thing, this question is referring to completion suggester filters, not regular query filters.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible with geolocation, but completion suggester will return documents with non-matching fields in addition to boosted matching fields when a single boost is supplied.